# How to execute an .sh file?

Tags: command-line, 14.04

I thought a sudo will work, but it says command not found:

```
sudo: ./eTax_ticinoPG13_inst_Linux.sh: command not found
nuc@nuc:~/Downloads$ ./eTax_ticinoPG13_inst_Linux.sh
bash: ./eTax_ticinoPG13_inst_Linux.sh: Keine Berechtigung
nuc@nuc:~/Downloads$ sudo ./eTax_ticinoPG13_inst_Linux.sh
sudo: ./eTax_ticinoPG13_inst_Linux.sh: command not found
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: First, make the .sh file executable with `chmod +x eTax_ticinoPG13_inst_Linux.sh`.

Answer (score 0):

Before you can execute your script, you must give it execution permissions. You can do it by executing:

> chmod +x eTax_ticinoPG13_inst_Linux.sh

You can also do it from nautilus by right clicking the file, going to Properties > Permissions, and then selecting Allow executing file as program.
Afterwards just start it with ./eTax_ticinoPG13_inst_Linux.sh and it will start.

Answer (score -1):

Make the .sh file executable with

```
chmod +x eTax_ticinoPG13_inst_Linux.sh
```

Then launch the script:

```
./eTax_ticinoPG13_inst_Linux.sh
```